# Radio de Preenchimento Obrigatório html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como coloco este campo de preenchimento obrigatório:

```
<p><h5><strong>Estado</strong></h5>
 <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="radio" name="Estado" value="Concluído">Concluído
```

Comment: Você deve além de adicionar o required no input, fazer uma validação no próprio php para uma maior segurança. Se você colocar qual o código que recebe esse post ou get após o envio do formulário. Talvez possamos te ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta acrescentar o atributo required na tag input. Ficaria algo do tipo:

```
<input type="radio" name="Estado" value="Concluído" required>Concluído
```

Comment: O mais seguro é fazer uma validação no próprio php. Pois o usuário pode pelo debugger simplesmente apagar o required.

Comment: Sim, é uma questão de segurança validar todos os campos tando no front quanto no back. Validar os dados no front serve principalmente para uma melhor experiência do usuário, que já vai saber oq preencheu de errado antes mesmo de enviar o formulário.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma verificação *front-end* com JavaScript (o `e.preventDefault();` vai impedir que o formulário seja enviado):

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
   if(!document.querySelector("input[name='Estado']").checked){
      alert("Marque o radio button");
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

E fazer a verificação no *back-end* no PHP (o mais importante!):

```
<?php
$Estado = $_POST['Estado'];

if(isset($Estado) && !empty($Estado)){
   echo "Estado foi checado";
}else{
   echo "Estado não foi checado";
}
?>
```